# Calling swing JPanels from actionlistener

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, actionlistener

im coding a project using various classes, but i got stuck when i press a button which call my main menu, here's my resumed code:

My main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        Dimension res = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

public void run(){

    Principal frame = new Principal("Program");

    frame.setSize(res.width,res.height);

    frame.setResizable(false);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.setUndecorated(true);

    frame.setVisible(true); 
    }
});`
```

Now, my principal:

```
 public class Principal extends JFrame implements ActionListener {


     private DetallesPrincipal DetallesPrincipal;

     private ClientesNuevo ClientesNuevo;

     private ClientesModificar ClientesModificar;

     Container p;

     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

     final JMenuItem Clientes1,Clientes2,Clientes3;

     final JMenuBar MenuBarMain = new JMenuBar();

 public Principal (String titulo){

      super(titulo); 

          setLayout(new BorderLayout());

      final JMenuBar MenuBarMain = new JMenuBar();

        MenuBarMain.setBackground(new Color(177,178,182));

      final JMenu MenuMainClientes;

        MenuMainClientes = new JMenu("Clientes");



            DetallesPrincipal = new DetallesPrincipal();
            ClientesNuevo = new ClientesNuevo();

                   p = getContentPane();

                MenuBarMain.add(MenuMainClientes);

                Clientes1 = new JMenuItem("Nueva ficha");

                    MenuMainClientes.add(Clientes1);

                            Clientes1.addActionListener(this);

                p.add(MenuBarMain, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

                p.add(DetallesPrincipal, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }


     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource()==Clientes1){

            p.removeAll();

            p.repaint();

            p.add(ClientesNuevo, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            p.revalidate();

            p.repaint();
        }
```

My ClientesNuevo:

```
public class ClientesNuevo extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    DetallesPrincipal m;

    GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

public ClientesNuevo() {


    Dimension size = getPreferredSize();
        size.width = 250;

        setPreferredSize(size);

        setBackground(new Color(111,114,123));

        TitledBorder Principal2 = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Te encuentras en clientes");

        Principal2.setTitleColor(new Color(100,100,100));

        Principal2.setTitleFont(new Font("Arial",0,24));

        Principal2.setTitlePosition(TitledBorder.BOTTOM);

        Principal2.setTitleJustification(TitledBorder.LEFT);

        setBorder(Principal2);


    JLabel Titulo1 = new JLabel("Nueva ficha cliente");

        Titulo1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma",0,36));

    JLabel Nombre = new JLabel("Nombre/Razón social ");

    JLabel Apellidos = new JLabel("Apellidos ");

    JLabel Cif = new JLabel("CIF/DNI ");

    JLabel Poblacion = new JLabel("Población ");

    JLabel Provincia = new JLabel("Provincia");

    JLabel Cpostal = new JLabel("Código postal");

    JLabel Telefono = new JLabel("Teléfono");

    JLabel Movil = new JLabel("Móvil");

    JLabel Notas = new JLabel("Notas");


    JTextField NombreText = new JTextField(25);

    JTextField ApellidosText = new JTextField(25);

    JTextField CifText = new JTextField(15);

    JTextField PoblacionText = new JTextField(15);

    JTextField ProvinciaText = new JTextField(20);

    JTextField CpostalText = new JTextField(15);

    JTextField TelefonoText = new JTextField(20);

    JTextField MovilText = new JTextField(20);

    JTextField NotasText = new JTextField(30);


    JButton Aceptar = new JButton("Aceptar");

    JButton Cancelar = new JButton("Cancelar");

        Aceptar.addActionListener(this);


    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();


            gc.gridx = 0;

            gc.gridy = 0;

            gc.weighty = 1;

            add(Titulo1, gc);


            gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;

            gc.gridx = 0;

            gc.gridy = 1;

            add(Nombre, gc);


            gc.gridx = 1;

            gc.gridy = 1;

            add(NombreText, gc);


            gc.gridx = 0;

            gc.gridy = 2;

            add(Apellidos, gc);

            gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;

            gc.gridx = 1;

            gc.gridy = 2;

            add(ApellidosText, gc);


            gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;

            gc.weightx = 1;

            gc.weighty = 1;

            gc.gridx = 0;

            gc.gridy = 3;

            add(Cif, gc);


            gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;

            gc.gridx = 1;

            gc.gridy = 3;

            add(CifText, gc);

            gc.gridx = 0;

            gc.gridy = 4;

            add(Poblacion, gc);


            gc.gridx = 1;

            gc.gridy = 4;

            add(PoblacionText, gc);

            gc.gridx = 2;

            gc.gridy = 4;

            add(Provincia, gc);


           gc.gridx = 2;

           gc.gridy = 7;

            add(Aceptar, gc);


           gc.gridx = 3;

           gc.gridy = 7;

            add(Cancelar, gc);
}



 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

               removeAll();

               repaint();

                m = new DetallesPrincipal();

            add(m,gc);

            revalidate();

            repaint();

    }


    }
```

Well, sorry for that walltext, but i am pretty lost, i just want call to my components of my DetallesPrincipal class, what's the better option to manage a program like this?

Comment: 1) Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) Don't extend frame or other top level containers.  Instead create & use an instance of one. 4) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Comment: Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm just a beginner who want to learn.

Comment: *"I'm sorry,"*  Don't be.  Just learn from the tips, & possibly [edit this question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17327352/edit) to fix the case of letters and the code indentation.

Comment: And exactly what is the problem? What is the expected behaviour vs actual behaviour??

Comment: My main menu DetallesPrincipal doesn't appear when i call it in my ClientesNuevo class from my ActionPerformed button.

Comment: So it works for others but not `DetallesPrincipal`? And in your question you provide no `DetallesPrincipal` source, only `ClientesNuevo`? Please post full source because if the exact same code works for other than the problem most likely lies within `DetallesPrincipal` class... Read @AndrewThompson comment with link on SSCCE!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well besides the fact that you dont post your full source or an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) I cannot fully test.

Looking at your code you are using the `removeAll()` method to switch between multiple `JPanel`s on a single `JFrame`/*container*.

The mistake I see you are making though is in the logic, as you attempt to switch between `JPanel`s within another `JPanel` rather than within your actual `JFrame`.

See this small example I created (allows a user to alternate between 2 `JPanel`s on a single `JFrame`/*container* which implements a [Singleton design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), can easily be changed for passing instance of `MainGUI` class to each `JPanel` the `MainGUI` spawns so that the `JPanel`s will have access to the single `MainGUI`s `swapPanel(JPanel p)` method):

[image]

[image]

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainGUI mainGUI = MainGUI.getInstance();
    }
}
class MainGUI {

    private JFrame frame;

    private static class SingletonHolder {

        public static final MainGUI INSTANCE = new MainGUI();
    }

    public static MainGUI getInstance() {
        return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE;
    }

    private MainGUI() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                frame = createJFrame();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private JFrame createJFrame() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Test");

        frame.add(new Panel1());//initial Jpanel to display

        frame.pack();
        return frame;
    }

    public void swapPanel(JPanel p) {
        frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
        frame.add(p);
        frame.pack();
        frame.revalidate();
        frame.repaint();
    }
}

class Panel1 extends JPanel {

    public Panel1() {
        JLabel labelPanel1 = new JLabel("Panel 1");
        JButton switchPanelButton = new JButton("Goto Panel 2");
        switchPanelButton.addActionListener(new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                MainGUI.getInstance().swapPanel(new Panel2());
            }
        });
        add(labelPanel1);
        add(switchPanelButton);
    }
}

class Panel2 extends JPanel {

    public Panel2() {
        JLabel labelPanel1 = new JLabel("Panel 2");
        JButton switchPanelButton = new JButton("Goto Panel 1");
        switchPanelButton.addActionListener(new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                MainGUI.getInstance().swapPanel(new Panel1());
            }
        });
        add(labelPanel1);
        add(switchPanelButton);
    }
}
```

An higher-level alternative to the above is a [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) *The CardLayout class manages two or more components (usually JPanel instances) that share the same display space.*:

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {

    private final static String PANEL1 = "panel 1";
    private final static String PANEL2 = "panel 2";

    public Test() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test();
            }
        });
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.add(new JLabel("Panel 1"));

        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.add(new JLabel("Panel 2"));

        //Create the panel that contains the "cards".
        final JPanel cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
        cards.add(panel1, PANEL1);
        cards.add(panel2, PANEL2);

        //create button to allow chnage to next card
        JButton buttonNext = new JButton(">");
        buttonNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) (cards.getLayout());//get cards
                cl.next(cards);
            }
        });

        //create button to allow chnage to previous card
        JButton buttonPrev = new JButton("<");
        buttonPrev.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) (cards.getLayout());//get cards
                cl.previous(cards);
            }
        });

        //create panel to hold buttons which will allow switching between cards
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(buttonPrev);
        buttonPanel.add(buttonNext);


        frame.add(cards);
        frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks :)... College been keeping me too busy!

Comment: oh sorry, i got some problems. Thank you very much, you gave me the vision of the problem as i wanted, thank you guys for your patience and dedication understanding a completely newbie like me :)

Comment: @user2525239 Its a pleasure. For interests sakes have a look at [this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14460/what-more-can-be-done-to-add-quality-to-swing-jpanel-drawings) near the bottom of the question is my FullScreen.java class. It allows natively setting a `JFrame` to fullscreen, or emulating fullscreen if its not natively supported. you would use it something like: 
                `FullScreen fs=new FullScreen(); if (fs.isSupported()) {
                    fs.setFullScreen(frame);
                } else {
                    fs.emulateFullScreen(frame);
                }`